# Using celery in python 3.3 on windows machine

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, celery

Currently i'm working on a project where I need to use Python 3.3 and celery.
I've been following the first steps tutorial, but i keep getting errors due to problems with librarys like _subprocess. Does annyone have some more information on this.
I also tried replacing the _subprocess with _winapi, with more errors as result. I'm open for anny suggestions. anny help on the mather would be appriciated.

ps: 
I'm working on a windows machine.
I'm using RabbitMq as broker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

celery doesn't yet work perfectly with python3.3 on windows it seems.
I ran the exact same setup on linux fedora and got it to work.
This problem should be fixed in future development of the package so be patient.